# Run resource with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I've have a PE exe as resource of another exe.
If i extract and write to file the resource, it run fine.
If i try to run with CreateProcess i get an error (impossible to run application)

this is my code for create process :

```
void BBStub::RunFromMemory(unsigned char* pImage, char* pPath)
{

  DWORD dwWritten = 0;
  DWORD dwHeader = 0;
  DWORD dwImageSize = 0;
  DWORD dwSectionCount = 0;
  DWORD dwSectionSize = 0;
  DWORD firstSection = 0;
  DWORD previousProtection = 0;
  DWORD jmpSize = 0;

  IMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
  IMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
  IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Sections[1000];

  PROCESS_INFORMATION peProcessInformation;
  STARTUPINFO peStartUpInformation;
  CONTEXT pContext;
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrib;

  char* pMemory;
  char* pFile;
  memcpy(&IDH, pImage, sizeof(IDH));
  memcpy(&INH, (void*)((DWORD)pImage + IDH.e_lfanew), sizeof(INH));

  dwImageSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
  pMemory = (char*)malloc(dwImageSize);
  memset(pMemory, 0, dwImageSize);
  pFile = pMemory;

  dwHeader = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
  firstSection = (DWORD)(((DWORD)pImage + IDH.e_lfanew) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
  memcpy(Sections, (char*)(firstSection), sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)*INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

  memcpy(pFile, pImage, dwHeader);

  if ((INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment) == 0)
  {
      jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
  }
  else
  {
      jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
      jmpSize += 1;
      jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
  }

  pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);

  for (dwSectionCount = 0; dwSectionCount < INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; dwSectionCount++)
  {
      jmpSize = 0;
      dwSectionSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].SizeOfRawData;
      memcpy(pFile, (char*)(pImage + Sections[dwSectionCount].PointerToRawData), dwSectionSize);

      if ((Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment) == 0)
      {
          jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize;
      }
      else
      {
          jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
          jmpSize += 1;
          jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
      }
      pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);
  }


  memset(&peStartUpInformation, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
  memset(&peProcessInformation, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
  memset(&pContext, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT));

  peStartUpInformation.cb = sizeof(peStartUpInformation);

  cout << peStartUpInformation.cb << endl;
  //      if (CreateProcess(NULL, pPath, &secAttrib, NULL, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &peStartUpInformation, &peProcessInformation))
  try
  {

      if (CreateProcess(NULL, pPath, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &peStartUpInformation, &peProcessInformation))
      {
          pContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
          GetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread, &pContext);
          VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), dwImageSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &previousProtection);
          WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), pMemory, dwImageSize, &dwWritten);
          WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (void*)((DWORD)pContext.Ebx + 8), &INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase, 4, &dwWritten);
          pContext.Eax = INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase + INH.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
          SetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread, &pContext);
          ResumeThread(peProcessInformation.hThread);
      }
      else {
          DWORD dw = GetLastError();
          cout << "Error" << endl;
          cout << dw << endl;
      }
  }
  catch (exception e)
  {
      cout << e.what();
  }
  free(pMemory);
}
```

any idea?

Comment: What is the error? i.e. is CreateProcess() returning an error (which), or just nothing happens, or?

Comment: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000000c)

Comment: Just to test, try adding a call to GetStartupInfo(&peStartUpInformation); before your call to CreateProcess(). I remember I had very weird behaviours with a badly initialized PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (although at a first glance yours look fine...)

Comment: At what part of the code above does the error arise? And how do you resolve references to other libraries?

Comment: Ok i try with  GetStartupInfo(&peStartUpInformation); I think that's a problem regarding starting exe from a memory due to a windows protection. im running win7 64

Comment: Now if i use createprocess like this : CreateProcess(NULL, pPath, &secAttrib, NULL, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &peStartUpInformation, &peProcessInformation) I have a "998" Error that mean "Invalid access to memory location"

Comment: You can't run a program "from memory" with `CreateProcess`. [Create process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) want a path to an executable.

Comment: I won't claim to understand everything being attempted here, but in the context, shouldn't you set EIP rather than EAX?

Comment: @Michael yes you can usi NULL on the first parameter and for examples argv[0] for the second parameter that want a cmdlines arguments.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError im coding in c++ and i dunno asm :)

Comment: @user3374388: read the MS documentation: "The lpApplicationName parameter can be NULL. In that case, the **module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the lpCommandLine string**. If you are using a long file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin; otherwise, the file name is ambiguous....

Comment: When you call `RunFromMemory(unsigned char* pImage, char* pPath)`, where does `pPath` point to ?

Comment: Thanks Michael. pPath is the argv 0.

Comment: You can't run an executable from memory, only from disk.

Comment: @Jonathan sorry but some peaple have code for doing that. i want to understand how.

Answer (score 1):

This is referred to as RunPE, you start a process suspended and then map your executable into it's memory, set the EIP to the entry point and resume the process.

The best code for doing this is from hasherezade and is available on her [github](https://github.com/hasherezade/demos/tree/master/run_pe)